# Expectation of indicator of an event can be expressed as the probability of the event

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

In Billingsley's seminal book "Probability and Measure" in the very first page he has indirectly mentioned one identity. Suppose $\Omega=\left( 0,1 \right]$. $\mathbb{P}$ being the probability measure defined on all such sets which can be expressed as finite disjoint union of intervals in $\left( 0,1 \right]$.  If $A=\cup_{k=1}^n \left(a_k, b_k\right]$, where $\left(a_k, b_k\right]$'s  are disjoint and the endpoints are in $\left(0,1\right]$, then $\mathbb{P}(A)= \sum_{k=1}^n (b_k-a_k)$. Now, define the indicator function $I_A(\omega)$ of the event $A$ . He used that $$\mathbb{P}(A)= \int _{0}^{1} I_A(\omega) d\omega$$ 
Of course this reminds me of the fact that $\mathbb{E} I_A=\mathbb{P}(A)$. But I need a simple reason behind this claim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you interpret the integral as **Riemann** then this follows from the definition of $I_A(\omega)$ and the usual **Riemann** integral of a step function. So, in this case, $I_A(\omega)$ will be $1$ on $A$. Now, $A=\cup_{k=1}^n \left(a_k, b_k\right]$. That means, $I_A(\omega)$ will be a step function where the steps are $1$ on each of the interval $\left(a_k, b_k\right]$. Thus the result easily follows. In fact this hint is mentioned in the first page itself which (in disguised form) indicate the applicability in deriving it.